# QGIS Issue with 3D view altitude binding

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d-map

I'm running into an issue with the 3D view in QGIS.

I have a DEM, which is displaying correctly and a building footprints polygon layer from OSM. It is draping correctly as a 2d polygon on the DEM in the 3D view, but when I go into the 3D View settings and enable 3D view rendering for the buildings layer to 'extrude' them, the 3D polygons are displaying far above the DEM vertically. I have switched the Altitude Binding to Terrain, which I believe should adhere them to the DEM since I have the DEM defined as the terrain in the 3D view, but nothing changes.

Comment: Have you consider Qgis2threejs to render your DEM and get a nicer 3D view of your data!

Comment: Yes, but it seems buggy to me. Almost every time I have tried it either A) doesn't show anything at all, or B) freezes and crashes QGIS when I try to add layers.

Comment: So I am using Qgis2threejs with a bit more success now (saving frequently), but I cannot figure out 2 things-1) can you save a view, and 2) when you export to gltf, is there a way to export the DEM texture (aerial imagery in this case) with it?

Comment: In my experience, Qgis2threejs is comparatively better than QGIS built-in 3D canvas. It produces instant 3D views and renders it decently. Yes, you can Save your 3D view as well as imagery draped over whether it is high resolution aerial or satellite imagery. There are numerous features to customize your perspective.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I have been using Qgis2threejs more. For saving the view, I meant save the camera position, etc. so that I can export the same view later on. Is that possible? Also, when I export the 3D geometry, the aerial imagery (texture) does not seem to export with it. Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

Use Qgis2threejs instead of built-in 3D canvas of QGIS. Comparatively, there are more options to render your DEM into perspective.

[image: 3D rendering in QGIS]

[image: 3D features]

Also, you can export the resultant image after making desire enhancements into .png file format;

[image]

You may also drape over aerial/satellite image;
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben. I think I'm not communicating my questions clearly... 1) is there a way to save the camera view for future use (not just exporting the image, but saving that view so you can return to the same view in Qgis2threejs at a future time)? and 2) In Qgis2threejs, I have the aerial imagery draped onto the DEM successfully, but when I export the 3D geometry to a GLTF file, it does not seem to bring the imagery (texture) with it, just the 3D geometry. Is this normal/is there a way to export the imagery with it?

Comment: Currently there is no such option to save camera view for future use. I am not sure about the latter issue you are facing with texture.

Comment: Does anyone know if the problem with altitude clamping within QGIS 3D has been solved?